# GitLab CI skip job in MR pipeline if label is present

Tags: label, gitlab-ci, jobs

This job runs anyway in a MR, is this a bug?

I tried different combinations as seen from the GitLab docs, but it continues to run or fails due to wrong syntax

```
somejob:
  stage: somestage
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS =~ /somelabel/
      when: never
  script:
    - echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS
```

the job runs anyway and I can see that the label is there

> $ echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS

> somelabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your first rule will always catch first. Rules stop evaluation on the first match. Because `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID` will always be present on an MR, that first rule will always match before your `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS` rule.

Change the order to get the intended effect:

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS =~ /somelabel/
      when: never
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
```